# SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(...) throws "InvalidOperationExeption : Headers are read-only, response has already started."

Tags: asp.net-core, signalr, asp.net-identity

I'm using Identity to manage the users in my app.

I Have a Hub with a method `SignIn(...)` to authenticate users. Inside that method I make a call to `SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(...)` But it keeps throwing the following exception:

`System.InvalidOperationException : Headers are read-only, response has already started`

What is causing that ? Is it because I'm using signalR ? And Is there a way to fix it ?

Here is the code I have on the server for now:

```
public class AccountHub : Hub
{
    private readonly IConfiguration configuration;
    private readonly UserManager<User> userManager;
    private readonly SignInManager<User> signInManager;

    public AccountHub(
        IConfiguration configuration,
        UserManager<User> userManager,
        SignInManager<User> signInManager)
    {
        this.configuration = configuration;
        this.userManager = userManager;
        this.signInManager = signInManager;
    }

    public async Task<SignInResultDto> SignIn(UserSignInDto user)
    {
        var result = await signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(user.Email, user.Password, false, false);
        if (!result.Succeeded)
            return new SignInResultDto { Successful = false, Error = "Username and password are invalid."};
        return new SignInResultDto { Successful = true };
    }
}
```

And on the client (a .Net client) i'm essencially doing this:

```
hubConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
            .WithUrl(this.navigationManager.ToAbsoluteUri("/Account"))
            .AddMessagePackProtocol()
            .Build();
await hubConnection.StartAsync();
var response = await hubConnection.InvokeAsync<SignInResultDto>("SignIn", userSignInData);
```

Comment: Could you please share more detailed code?

Comment: @Rena here. I Updated the question. If you need anything more I can provide just tell me.

Comment: `SignInManager` uses `IHttpContextAccessor` to get the "current" `HttpContext` and I assume set response headers on it. SignalR doesn't follow a single http request or even run during any http request and as such will either not have an `HttpContext` to reference, or will have an `HttpContext` that is already being written to, hence the error you're seeing.

Comment: @Brennan are you aware of a way to fix this or a workarround ?

Comment: Do auth in the normal auth middleware and apply `[Authorize]` to your Hub or Hub methods that require an authorized user.

Comment: @Brennan what do you call the 'normal' auth middleware ? Can you provide a code example ? as an answer maybe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So [this issue](https://github.com/openiddict/openiddict-core/issues/578) clearly says that `SignInManager` sets some cookies when it authenticates the user. SignalR apparently doesn't allow to modify the headers of the http connection after the connection is established. Hence the error.